# Email validation using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, email-validation

Hello All
I am facing problem with email validation. One group of tester test my web page and they reject my development due to email validation.

They are entering email like abc@gmail.123.com, abc@gmail.com.com, abc@gmail.123.com
etc...

I am not getting this kind of regular expression which validation this kind of emails.
Specially .com, .net, .ca, .123

Is there any regular expression or javascript validation which can validate this kind of emails?

Any idea about this

Comment: What is your question, and more importantly, *where is your code*?

Comment: And what regular expression do you use?

Comment: good luck: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Tell those testers to go peddle their papers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do some research on this.  Email addresses cannot, repeat **CANNOT** easily be verified by regular expressions.

If you are looking to just validate the address portion user@host.domain that is doable. But validating "Foo Bar" <foo@bar.baz> is not easily verifiable.

I would suggest looking at the RFCs with regard to SMTP specifically with regard to addressing to possibly craft a regular expression that will do what you want.

Comment: [RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) may help

Comment: thanks @martin (was going to say RFC-822 but that's old skool)

Answer (score 0):

The following example javascript function should look for email addresses that start with letters or numbers.

```
function emailValidate(emailValue){
    var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$/;
    if(pattern.test(emailValue))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly OK for local parts of email addresses to start with digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = 'abc@gmail.123.com'
if (email.match('^[A-z0-9._%-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}$') == email) {
    alert('email is valid!')
} else {
    alert('you have an error in your email')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [first result](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=regexp%20email) gives some good information:

The page is a good starting point on regular expression and describes some of the trade-offs in matching e-mail adresses. As stated by others, there is no standard way. Verifying e-mail adresses with regular expressions is not as easy as it may seem.

You could use the following regexp as a starting point:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

Have a look at [the article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: So you would disallow lower-case letters in email addresses?

Comment: I would not. I'd just set my regexp engine to case insensitive (as mentioned in the article).

Comment: Downvote my answer and upvote a comment with the exact same link. Did anyone actually read the article?!?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers but here's my 2 pence: there is no one regex that will validate all emails correctly with a zero false positive rate. Yes there is the RFC spec, and yes there is a (very long & nasty) regex to match it, but this still wont cover everything: some email systems support email addresses that do not comply with this.

Any of the shorter/simpler regexes suggested here will work for 95 - 99% of email addresses, but not everything. And even if an email address *is* of a valid format, you still don't know it's actually a real address. Even sending a test message to that address doesn't help: many email servers will silently drop incoming emails for non-existent addresses. So really there is no point in checking format validity: you still have no idea if the address is good or not.

**So the only e-mail validation I recommend is checking for the "@" character**. That *must* be in every address. Is very simple, will reject total garbage, e.g bot rubbish, and will ensure that no legitimate addresses are rejected.

**Tl;dr: It's pointless to check for format validity as regexes are insufficient and you don't know if a valid format address is good or not anyway. Just check for the "@" character.**

Answer (score -1):

you can use this function

```
function isemail(field){
    with (field){
      apos=value.indexOf("@");
      apos2=value.lastIndexOf("@");
      dotpos=value.lastIndexOf(".");
      if (apos<1 || dotpos-apos<2 || apos!=apos2 || value=="example@example.com")
                return false;
      else return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with "example@example.com"?

Comment: Actually I like the idea behind disallowing example@example.com. But there will be a thousand more dummy adresses to handle.

Comment: I prevent it because i used to use it as the default value in the text input, that's all

Answer (score -1):

This regex should work:

```
 /^(([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$/g
```

Comment: negative voting on 3 answers regarding the regular expression?! why?